# Xcode 12.4 crashes when opening any project

Tags: swift, xcode, xcodeproj

Xcode keeps crashing whenever I try to run any `.xcodeproj` or `.xcworkspace` project.
Solutions I've tried are: reinstalling Xcode, deleting derived data, and deleting xcuserstate folder.
Xcode keeps failing with the below error:

```
Process:               Xcode [7099]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               12.4 (17801)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-17801000000000000~7 (12D4e)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       839994694
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [7099]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-03-13 11:03:31.401 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 11.0.1 (20B29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        007E7CE0-17B1-C3EF-5191-4E8908451B4E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       310A38F4-3A1F-4C76-8D12-A255873336E7

Time Awake Since Boot: 28000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       570 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 12D4e
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-17801/IDEKit/Workspace/IDEWorkspaceDocument.m:3270
Details:  (tabController) should not be nil.
Object:   <IDEWorkspaceDocument: 0x7fa04eecbff0>
Method:   -commitStateToDictionary:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa045904c20>{number = 1, name = main}
Open FDs: 41/7168
Hints:
```

Comment: Same for me. XC12.4. Gets into this state periodically, then as SwiftyDev says, I open it via the menu instead of the Welcome dialog. That trashes the current window/tab/etc user settings and is fine for a while. Til it happens again. Haven't tried the newly released XC12.5 yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same problem as you but on my side Xcode crashes only when I open a project directly from the fast project opening window (the one that opens when Xcode is launched)
Try to open the project through the Finder or from the terminal directly with the command open /nameProject/xcWorkspace

I don't have any problems with this method.